# Runtime error. Java. Create a class, Sort that displays four integer numbers in increasing order

Tags: java, sorting, runtime-error

I am new in programming, just 1 month. I should create a class, Sort that displays four integer numbers in increasing order. I learned something from here. Unfortunately, this program doesn't run, when compiling there is no error. The error message looks like this:

stderr
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Sort.main(Main.java:9)
```

Here is program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Sort
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int a,b,c,d;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter four numbers: ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();
        b = keyboard.nextInt();
        c = keyboard.nextInt();
        d = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (a>b) {
            int temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;;
        }
        if (b>c) {
            int temp = b;
            b = c;
            c = temp;
        }
        if (c>d) {
            int temp = c;
            c = d;
            d = temp;
        }
        if (a>b) {
            int temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
        if (b>c) {
            int temp = b;
            b = c;
            c = temp;
        }
        if (a>b) {
            int temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
        System.out.println("The numbers :" + a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call your program? And how do you input the numbers? I just copied your code into my IDE and it runs fine. Additionally, which is line 9?

Comment: Another confusing thing: Your class is not public (which it should) and is named `Sort`, whereas the source code is placed in a file called `Main.java`? Hmmm ... Name your file `Sort.java` and make your class public.

Comment: Actually, I don't know exactly how it reads numbers inputted since it didn't run. What do you mean by which is line 9?

Comment: Did you run this code directly from your IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans etc.)? I could imagine you might get that error if your IDE does not allow you to provide input on stdin.

Comment: No, file is named Sort. I am using BlueJ (which was recommended by Udacity), and it doesn't even show any errors, just stuck. So, I tried run it on online compiling(ideone.com) and here if class is public there is such error: Main.java:2: error: class Sort is public, should be declared in a file named Sort.java
public class Sort. However, the file is named Sort(at least it shows Sort in Total Commander)

Comment: Your posted stacktrace contained the line "at Sort.main(Main.java:9)". This means the error originated from a statement in line 9 in the file Main.java. Which of the posted lines is this line 9? Is it maybe the first call to `nextInt`? Additionally, you are wrapping a `Scanner` around `System.in`, which is the standard input stream. That means, input is read from the console. You simply type it with your keyboard. In fact, you can type a single line with four numbers "4 3 2 1", then hit return ... or four times write one number and hit return. It will all work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your help. I have learnt how to run java files with command prompt and it was successful

Answer (score 1):

NoSuchElementException will be thrown if input is exhausted, i.e. the nextInt() method has no int to return. To fix this you can check if the scanner has more ints with `hasNextint()` before you call nextInt(). This should get rid of the error, I believe however that this is due to the program not reading all input so maybe should rewrite the input part.

Comment: hmmm, so I should change like this:  a = keyboard.hasNextInt();
        b = keyboard.hasNextint();
        c = keyboard.hasNextint();
        d = keyboard.hasNextint();

Comment: No, you have to check before assiging to variable:

int a = -1;
if(scanner.hasNextint()) {
// Data exists
a = scanner.nextInt();
} else {
// No int input given, do stuff;
}

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out